# How to fetch saved data from SQLite database in a screen for a specific transaction?

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, android-database, sqflite

I am making an app in which users can save the transaction data which they can do by filling out the following form [image: form]
The transactions then will be saved in the database and can be shown to users on the following screen
[image]
The details which are getting saved by the form are Name, Amount Comment, Category, date and if the transaction is unnecessary. But the details which I want to show in image 2 are Name, amount and date. Now for viewing the rest of the details the user can click on the specific transaction and a new page should open showing the details of the transaction like this
[image: show]

How can I do it? I mean if I click on the transaction above page should display.

I am creating my database using the following code:

```
await database.execute(
      "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_EXPENSES ("
      "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
      "$COLUMN_NAME TEXT,"
      "$COLUMN_AMOUNT INTEGER,"
      "$COLUMN_UNNECESSARYEXPENSES INTEGER,"
      "$COLUMN_CATEGORY TEXT,"
      "$COLUMN_DATETIME TEXT,"
      "$COLUMN_COMMENTS TEXT"
      ")",
    );
```

Edit:

The code which I am using for mapping:

```
class expense {
  int id;
  String name;
  int amount;
  bool isUnnecessaryExpenses;
  String category;
  DateTime dateTime;
  String pickedDate;
  String comments;

expense({this.id, this.name, this.amount, this.isUnnecessaryExpenses,  this.category, this.dateTime, this.pickedDate, this.comments});

Map toMap() {
  var map = {
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_NAME: name,
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_AMOUNT: amount,
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_UNNECESSARYEXPENSES: isUnnecessaryExpenses ? 1  : 0,
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_CATEGORY: category,
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_DATETIME: pickedDate,
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_COMMENTS: comments,
  };

  if (id != null) {
    map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_ID] = id;
  }

  return map;
  }

 expense.fromMap(Map map) {
  id = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_ID];
  name = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_NAME];
  amount = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_AMOUNT];
  isUnnecessaryExpenses = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_UNNECESSARYEXPENSES]  == 1;
  category= map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_CATEGORY];
  pickedDate = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_DATETIME];
  comments = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_COMMENTS];
  }
 }
```

And I am displaying transactions in image 2 with the help of following code:

```
ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Text(
                    expensess.name
                        .substring(0, 1)
                        .toUpperCase(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  expensess.name ?? "Title",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  "Amount: ${expensess.amount.toString()}"
                      "\nDate: ${expensess.pickedDate}\n"
                  ,style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ViewTransaction()));
                      }
                  ));
                }
```

viewTransaction() is as follows:

```
class ViewTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_ViewTransactionState createState() => _ViewTransactionState();
}
```

class _ViewTransactionState extends State {
@override

```
void initState(){
 super.initState();
 DatabaseProvider.db.getExpenses().then(
      (expenseList) {
    BlocProvider.of<ExpenseBloc>(context).add(SetExpenses(expenseList));
    },
  );
 }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  expense expenses;
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.white, title: Text(expenses.name),),

  );
 } 
}
```

Please help.
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: You can simply pass the expenses details in the third screen's constructor parameters.

Comment: Hi @YazanWYusuf thanks for your reply but I am new in flutter can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: Hi @YazanWYusuf, I have updated the question please check it again